# Insert to clustered hive table from spark

Tags: hive, pyspark, bigdata

i'm trying to do some performance optimization on the data storage. the idea is to use the bucketing/clustering of hive to bucket the available devices (based on column id). my current approach is inserting data from an external table based on parquet files into the table. As a result it applies the bucketing.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE bucketed_table PARTITION (year, month, day)
SELECT id, feature, value, year, month, day
FROM parquet_table ;
```

I would like to get rid of this step in between by ingesting the data directly into that table directly from PySpark 2.1. 
Executing the same statement using SparkSQL leads to different results. Adding the cluster by clause

```
 INSERT INTO TABLE bucketed_table PARTITION (year, month, day)
    SELECT id, feature, value, year, month, day
    FROM parquet_table cluster by id ;
```

still leads to different output files.

This leads to two questions:
1) What is the right way to insert into a clustered hive table from spark?
2) Does writing with clustered by statement enable the benefits of the hive metastore on the data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that it's supported as of yet. I'm currently using Spark 2.3 and it fails, as opposed to succeeding and corrupting your data store.

Checkout the jira ticket [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19256) if you want to track its progress